# How to extract methods with default parameters from struct

Tags: swift, struct

I wrote a struct for inputting log. The method in the struct takes default parameters to obtain log information. Now I want to reuse these methods in other struct. I thought of protocol, but the methods in protocol are not allowed to take default parameters. The struct does not allow inheritance. Is there any good way？ Thanks

```
public struct TrackLog: OptionSet {
   public static let drag = TrackLog(rawValue: 1<<0)
   public static let crop = TrackLog(rawValue: 1<<1)
   public static let sound = TrackLog(rawValue: 1<<2)
   public static let thumbnail = TrackLog(rawValue: 1<<3)
   public static let allLog = TrackLog(rawValue: 1111<<0)
   public let rawValue: Int
   public init(rawValue: Int) {
       self.rawValue = rawValue
   }

   /// Methods I want to reuse in other structs
   public func error(_ log: Any? = nil, file:String = #file, function:String = #function, line:Int = #line) {
   /// Output after processing logs
    }

   /// Methods I want to reuse in other structs
   public func log(_ title: Any? = nil, log: Any? = nil, file:String = #file, function:String = #function, line:Int = #line) {
   /// /// Output after processing logs
   }}
```

Comment: Do you need to call the methods on a protocol type? If not, you can just put them in a protocol extension, which _does_ allow optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to override those common methods in some of your structs, you can put them in a protocol extension (which does allow duplicate) and have the protocol be empty.

```
protocol Loggable { }
extension Loggable {
    public func error(_ log: Any? = nil, file:String = #file, function:String = #function, line:Int = #line) {
         ...
     }

    public func log(_ title: Any? = nil, log: Any? = nil, file:String = #file, function:String = #function, line:Int = #line) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
extension TrackLog: Loggable { }
```

and `TrackLog` will have all those logging methods.

Do note that if you declare another `error` or `log` method in `TrackLog` with the same signature, it will *hide* the one declared in the protocol extension.